# Unable to use Selenium to login into Quora

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Selenium to scrape some data(according to the terms and conditions), but I first need to login. I have the following code, and the name was gotten from the inspect element in firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
elem="";
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
elem.send_keys("email")
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
elem.send_keys("password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

However , selenium keeps telling me :

```
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `quit()` in the middle of your web-scraping browser session - you basically close the browser and then continue sending commands to it which leads to the socket error.

Instead, put all the code into under the `try/finally`:

```
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email"))
    )
    elem.send_keys("email")

    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))
    )
    elem.send_keys("password")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

---

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

As for this problem, the reason is that there are multiple elements with `name="email"` and `name="password"` on the page. You are locating the one that is invisible and trying to interact with it. You should improve your locator and make it more specific:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".regular_login [name=email]"))
)
elem.send_keys("email")

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".regular_login [name=password]"))
)

elem.send_keys("password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I keep getting this selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with, any ideas?

Comment: @user2578666 okay, that's a different problem, but let me take a look.

Comment: @user2578666 don't change the initial question please. This makes the answer non-relevant. Please revert the edit.